# Equivalent of memalign in cuda

Tags: c, cuda, memory-alignment

I am trying to parallelize a C function using CUDA. I noticed that there are several structs which are being passed as pointers to this function. 
With the [unified memory view](http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/), I have identified and modified `malloc()` to `cudaMallocManaged()`.

But, now there is a allocation using `memalign()`. I want to achieve a similar task as that was done by `cudaMallocManaged()`.

Does such an equivalent exists ? If no, then what needs to be done?

This is how the `memalign()` allocation line looks:

```
float *data = (float*) memalign(16, some_integer*sizeof(float));
```

Comment: According to the [cuda c programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#data-transfer-between-host-and-device) memory allocated with cuda allocation functions is always aligned to at least 256 bytes. As far as I know you cannot specify other alignments.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to register an existing host memory buffer like this:

```
float *data = (float*) memalign(16, some_integer*sizeof(float));
cudaHostRegister((void *)data, some_integer*sizeof(float), cudaHostRegisterDefault);
```

after registration `data` should behave the same as memory allocated with `cudaMallocManaged`. Check the return value from the `cudaHostRegister` call, if it fails, you have chosen an incompatible alignment.